# SKNodes don't show in scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I had scene set up and everything worked well. It looked like this:[image]

But the controller was set up in Main.storyboard and I wanted to get rid of it. So I did something like this:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = GameViewController()
```

in appDelegate and this:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view = SKView()
}
```

in GameViewController to load it. First time, the scene loaded, but only the green background, no other nodes. (Node counter showed the correct number of nodes.)

So I tried setting the ignoresSiblingOrder both true and false, all options of scene.scaleMode and the best result that I achieved was with scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill. Looked like this:
[image]

EDIT: 
Position for circles:

```
greenOne.position = CGPoint(x: greenOne.radius + sticksOffset, y: greenOne.radius + sticksOffset)
redOne.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - redOne.radius - sticksOffset / 2, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2)
```

Tried this and redOne appeared next to the green

```
redOne.position = CGPoint(x: redOne.radius + 100, y: 200)
```

It seems that the view didn't fit the screen and is just too large.

Comment: So only the green circle and background is showing ?

Comment: Yes, only the green one, although all the circle has the same setting..

Comment: I see, could you please provide more code? Maybe show how the circles are set up.

Comment: Oh, probably found the problem - 
The position of green circle is made just with some offset.
The others have `self.frame.maxX` in position.
What do you think? (I will post code in a minute)

Comment: The Green positioning should be fine. If you don't specify a position it will automatically put the object at position 0,0. Have you checked whether or not your objects have a zPosition assigned to them/

Comment: I just edited the code in the end. I already tried different values of zPosition. but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing view init in GameViewController:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.view = SKView(frame: UIScreen.main.applicationFrame)
}
```

The old version of view had zero width and height, so the GameScene didn't get any dimensions.

Comment: `applicationFrame property is deprecated` since iOS 9.0. You may want to use `UIScreen.bounds`, or just `self.view = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)`